# How to play a PS RTP stream with Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'm tring to play a RTP video stream which is coming from an IP Camera. From SDP, the RTP stream contains a MPEG PS stream in it, but I cannot found any proper depay plugin to get PS packet from RTP packet in Gstreamer plugins(good, bad, ugly). The steam can be played by VLC by using the follow SDP.
Can anyone give me a advice to play the stream by Gstreamer?

`v=0 m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96 c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1 a=rtpmap:96 MP2P/90000`